# No navigation bar showing in Android Studio AVDs

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I'm getting user reports of the system navigation bar on some Android devices overlaying my app's bottom-of-the-screen menu. I cannot reproduce this as none of my AVDs are displaying the navigation bar. I've tried creating new AVDs from scratch without the "Hardware Buttons" option checked. Nope. Downloaded official skins and applied those. Nope. Edited the hw.mainKeys settings in the AVD's config.ini and hardware-qemu.ini files. Nope. None of the default phones or tablets are showing navigation bars, on my app or a new "Hello World" app built from scratch. Is there some system-wide setting that might account for this? I'm on Android Studio Giraffe on an M1 Mac.